# Producing multiple plots for multiple timestep values

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

I am aiming to show the accuracy of a numerical solution and how this varies with the value of timestep chosen. The numerical solution is produced using the following code:

```
def f(te3):
    y3 = -r3*(te3 - te_surr) #y is the derivative
    return y3


for i in range(1, len(t3)):
    te3[i] = te3[i-1] + f(te3[i-1])*dt
```

These numerical solutions are then plotted:

```
plt.plot(t3,te3)
```

Originally, dt was chosen to be 0.1. I am trying to show the various plots produced for different values of timesteps: 0.05, 0.01, etc. However I am unsure how to implement this into my code other than manually typing out each value of dt,

```
dt2 = 0.05
dt3 = 0.025
dt4 = 0.01
dt5 = 0.005
dt6 = 0.001
```

then changing the code shown above for each dt value and so forth. Is there a way I can store these values as a list or an array and use this to plot the values?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use a dictionary to hold `te3` for each `dt`. For example:

```
dt_values = [0.05, 0.025, 0.1, 0.05, 0.001]

my_te3 = {0.05:[1,2,3], 0.025:[1,2,3]}

for i, dt in zip(range(1, len(my_te3[0.05])), dt_values):
    my_te3[dt][i] = my_te3[dt][i-1] + f(my_te3[dt][i-1])*dt
```

Then, to plot, you just need to loop the keys:

```
for te3 in my_te3.itervalues(): 
    plt.plot(t3,te3)
```

Note that `itervalues` only works in Python 2.7. For Python 3, use `.values` instead.

Comment: I'm getting the message "x and y must have same first dimension" when trying to plot, any idea why?

Comment: `t3` and `te3` do not have the same size. They must have the same number of components in order to be plotted.